# Preprocess execution is not where my view is

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to create a preprocess function to my custom view. Template is called as expected but my preprocess is called at beginning of html and left my entire page blank.

If I change to default template (`views_view_unformatted.html.twig`) the execution of `theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()` works as expected, right on my view is. But if change to `views_view__custom.html.twig` the execution of `theme_preprocess_views_view__custom()` occur at beginning of html!

This is the normal behavior? Or something is wrong? I just want to create my custom view template and create a preprocess function for it.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 it is possible to have preprocess functions for the theme suggestions.

So let's say if your template for the View is views-view--test-view--block-1.html.twig, you would have following preprocess functions:

- THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view__test_view__block_1
- THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view__test_view
- THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view